# merge all values of keys in array php

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

Don't know this question is asked before or not, cannot find after lot of searching.

My array looks like this,

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["userId"]=>
      string(3) "421"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(1) {
      ["userId"]=>
      string(3) "329"
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["userId"]=>
      string(3) "329"
    }
  }
  [4]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["userId"]=>
      string(3) "329"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(1) {
      ["userId"]=>
      string(3) "421"
    }
  }
}
```

What I want is,

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["userId"]=>
      string(3) "421"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(1) {
      ["userId"]=>
      string(3) "329"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(1) {
      ["userId"]=>
      string(3) "329"
    }
    [3]=>
    array(1) {
      ["userId"]=>
      string(3) "329"
    }
    [4]=>
    array(1) {
      ["userId"]=>
      string(3) "421"
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried with `array_merge`, `array_combine` and a lot of `foreach()` loops. But didn't get luck for desired output.

Don't know how to do this. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can flatten your array like this:

```
$arr = array(array(['user' => 1], ['user' => 2]), ['user' => 3]);
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($arr));
foreach($iterator as $val) {
  $flattened_arr[0][] = $val;
}
var_dump($flattened_arr);
```

**UPDATE:** If you don't want to use `RecursiveIteratorIterator`, the you can also do it like this using [`array_walk_recursive()`](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_walk_recursive.asp):

```
$non_flat_arr = array(array(['user' => 1], ['user' => 2]), ['user' => 3]);
$objTmp = (object) array('flat_arr' => array());
array_walk_recursive($non_flat_arr, create_function('&$v, $k, &$t', '$t->flat_arr[] = $v;'), $objTmp);
var_dump([ 0 => $objTmp->flat_arr]);
```

This will give you the output as:

```
array:1 [
  0 => array:3 [
    0 => 1
    1 => 2
    2 => 3
  ]
]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much. But what if `RecursiveIteratorIterator` do not supports on the live site server?(Do not know what professionally or technically 'live site server' called as).

Comment: @KeyurK - If you find this answer correct and helpful then accept & upvote this answer as it motivates me to give answers to other questions like this and helps others to quickly find the correct answer!

Comment: Yes will do. Surely.